# Filters in IR alarm circuit

Tags: filter

Electronics student here, so i'm printing a IR receiver for a project of my school.
I'm trying to understand the filtering part of the circuit.

The signal is received through the BP104 photodiode and then passes in a filtering/amplifying part of the circuit to be decoded then by a LMC567 tone decoder. Here's the schematic:

[image]

So far this is what I know :

Q1, Q2, Q3 and Q5 are Darlington pairs, to amplify the signal.

My questions are :

C2 and C3 would be low pass filters ?

What is the purpose of R11/C7, R7/C5 and C11/R14 ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q2/Q3 is a Darlington pair configuration (not Q5/Q1).

C3 is a DC-blocking capacitor, so that only the signal goes into Q2 and not the DC bias given by D1/R10.

R14 provides DC bias for Q5, and C11 will short circuit R14 for AC signals, giving a high AC gain for Q5.

C2 is a *bootstrap* capacitor, providing a higher input impedance at Q2.

Now think of Q2/Q3/Q5/Q1 as a high gain amplifier (like an opamp).

From the output you have a (frequency-dependent) voltage divisor given by R5/C5 and R11/C7. The signal in the midpoint is used as feedback to the amplifier by means of R6.

You can do the math for this voltage divider; I suspect that the overall circuit is a band-pass amplifier.